# Auto-Update Fails

Tags: permissions, upgrade

I'm installing my first WP site for a client and I either pulled a recent, but not entirely up to date version or there was a very recent update. I'm being prompted to upgrade, which is fine, but it won't complete with the following:

```
Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.4.1-partial-0.zip…

Unpacking the update…


Warning: copy(/opt/home/me/dev/client/www/wp-admin/includes/update-core.php) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/home/me/dev/client/www/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 200
Could not copy files.

Installation Failed
```

It feels like a permissions issue, but what I can't find -- other than [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions) -- is a comprehensive list of what the perms should look like (particularly at the directory level). At this point, `wp-content` and all of its content is sitting at 777 (more open than I'd like).

I'm trying to use the auto install (presumably running as the apache user) on a code base in my home directory. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`wp-content` should be `755`, otherwise WordPress will *think* it has global write access, and won't fallback to the FTP filesystem method if it doesn't.

Might be worth checking if PHP is running in safe mode - this can also be the troublemaker (though I'm aware WordPress *can* still upgrade with it on).

Comment: Is this correct? According to the link I was reading (http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions), `wp-content` is "User-supplied content: intended to be completely writable by all users (owner/user, group, and public)."

Comment: Hmm, that might be legacy documentation there. Since 2.5, WP introduced filesystem transports (direct, FTP, SSH & sockets) to accomodate for various setups & ownership conflicts. Either way, `wp-content` should never be `777` (technically, neither should any other directory).